# Sending get request to an Laravel API using axios in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, rest, api, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created an api using Laravel 5.5 and tested it in Postman. So, in Postman it's working correctly, BUT when I try to connect it from my frontend I'm getting some errors. I'm using Vue.js on frontend.

**Here's the request from frontend using axios:**

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        posts: {}
      }
    }, 
    created() {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/users',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,     
          'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'   
        }
      }).then(response => {
          this.posts = response.data;
          console.log(this.posts[0].body);          
        }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error.message);          
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

**And the api route:**

```
Route::get('users', 'UserController@index');
```

**I'm getting such an error:** 
[image]

An API is running on `localhost:8000` via `php artisan serve` command.
And Vue.js app is running on `localhost:8000` via `yarn run dev` command.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: the headers should be coming from the server, not the client. i.e. the server should respond to the client with a request including the headers you wrote

Comment: Could u please include an example? Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `Access-Control` headers from your axios request but you also need to configure your Laravel application to accept requests from foreign origins.

For that, you need to add CORS headers support in your Laravel application. You can use [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package to easily implement the functionality.

But if you want **to do it manually**:

**Use this middleware:**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORS {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
        ];
        if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }

}
```

**Register it:**

To use CORS middleware you have to register it first in your app\Http\Kernel.php file like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        //other middlewares
        'cors' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CORS',
    ];
```

**and then apply the middleware in required routes:**

```
Route::get('test', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'TestController@test'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved a lot of time) It works perfectly.

Comment: And one more question.. Is it a good practice to separate frontend and backend like so? Because Vue.js comes with Laravel out of the box. I mean separating Laravel and Vue..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cors headers in the server config , not your request.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin must be set to *
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers must be set to Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept

Here is an nginx config example.

https://gist.github.com/tomkersten/1323477

And apache2 instructions

https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html